# IOS : Releasing variable with @property (nonatomic, retain)

Tags: ios

Should the Variables with the @property nonatomic and retain be released explicitly.

```
@interface MyScreenViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWebView* greetingView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView* greetingView;

- (void)dealloc {
  [greetingView release];
}
```

Is release in delloc method Required ???

Comment: You **must** read this before proceeding with any more coding: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ofcourse. YES you should release your properties with retain,copy and don't for assign. You set the property to Nil in viewDidUnload.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
     [super viewDidUnload];

     self.greetingView = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
     [greetingView release],greetingView = nil;

     [super dealloc];
}
```

Refer memory management in UIViewController Class reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Memory is a critical resource in iOS, and view controllers provide built-in support for reducing their memory footprint at critical times. The UIViewController class provides some automatic handling of low-memory conditions through its didReceiveMemoryWarning method, which releases unneeded memory. Prior to iOS 3.0, this method was the only way to release additional memory associated with your custom view controller class but in iOS 3.0 and later, the viewDidUnload method may be a more appropriate place for most needs.

When a low-memory warning occurs, the UIViewController class purges its views if it knows it can reload or recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the viewDidUnload method to give your code a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view hierarchy, including objects loaded with the nib file, objects created in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily at runtime and added to the view hierarchy. Typically, if your view controller contains outlets (properties or raw variables that contain the IBOutlet keyword), you should use the viewDidUnload method to relinquish ownership of those outlets or any other view-related data that you no longer need.

Comment: in viewDidUnload `self.greetingView = nil;` is set and then delloc is called and the release is performed. But the variable value is nil. Does this work as expected?

Comment: If a message is called on a class when its value is nil, it does nothing and returns nil.  So if greetingView is nil, [greetingView release] does nothing.  Which is no problem.

Comment: Yes... Then we have not released it... Since it set to nil, before dealloc is called. As shown above.

Comment: @nanjunda this is right way to do it. Refer to memory management guide. Setting property to nil releases it and sets to nil.

Comment: @Matthew If a message is sent to an Object not class. You send messages to objects not classes.

Comment: Actually, the class was released when you called self.greetView = nil.  Because you are calling it with "self.", it will run the synthesized method setGreetView: which will send the release method for you.  So when it gets to the -(void)dealloc method *it is already released* and when [greetView release] is called, nothing happens.  However, you want to keep the code *exactly the way* Nikita has described, because it is possible viewDidLoad will *not* get called before dealloc.  Your code might follow a different path.  So you must also release in dealloc.

Comment: @MatthewGillingham Can you please release objects not classes.

Comment: Why not just have self.greetingView = nil; in dealloc. From what @MatthewGillingham said it sounds like it accomplishes the same as [greetingView release],greetingView = nil;

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should release it, because it is a retained property.  Anything property that is retained (or copied) should be released by the same class (if it is assigned, it doesn't need to be released).

Retain is basically like a class saying, "I am going to be using this other class, so keep it around in memory."  `dealloc` is where the class that said that is, itself, going to be removed from memory.  So if the class that needed your retained property is about to go away, that object itself should be deallocated, too.

Otherwise it is just going to sit there in memory, when nothing else in the program needs it.  And if that kind of thing keeps happening, you will run out of memory.

(Also, make sure you that you call `[super dealloc]` at the end of of your dealloc method.)