# iOS leak instrument retain count

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

My leak instrument indicates that I have a retain count of two yet I only release the object once. I've looked through my code and I couldn't find the second allocation. Is there a way for the leak instrument to indicate to me all the locations where the object is allocated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, being able to at least know what kind of object is leaking is already a big deal. Have you tried the **Static Analyzer**? Because it might help you dealing with this stuff. Another thing, just because you are allocating once, it doesn't mean you only have a retain count of one. Most of the problems related with the memory management (from my experience) are related with poor architecture, in no time you find yourself with spaghetti code. Tell me do you pass your object to another class? For instance, as a delegate?

Comment: It turns out the issue I am having is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685952/ios-releasing-variable-with-property-nonatomic-retain

I am passing an object to a new object. This is increasing the retain count.

Comment: Well, glad you found your problem.